# GLib development libraries not found

Tags: ubuntu, glib

I am trying to build target images (kernel,rootfs) for Freescale's imx25PDK kit using LTIB. I am getting an error while building "dbus-glib" package, that error is Configure error : GLib development libraries not found".
Now, I have already installed the package "libglib2.0-dev", so I don't know any exactly which package it needs. I have also tried various other development libraries (libgtk2.0-dev, libdbusmenu-glib-dev, libdbusglib-2.4-dev, etc. ) but the error still persists. There are various threads on different forums regarding this, but no one has any satisfactory answers (...or I missed it). I have found glib-devel-x.x RPM packages for Redhat on certain sites () but still I am trying to find packages for Ubuntu.
I am using ubuntu 10.04(LTS) Lucid Lynx.
Any insights would be of great help...thanks.

Comment: I would guess at glib-dev for the Freescale and not the host architecture.

Comment: ok, I ,ll gv it a try. First I have to see if the option is available. Will check it out and let you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve-o correctly said :

> I would guess at glib-dev for the Freescale and not the host architecture. – Steve-o Jul 25 at 8:39

the problem was that I needed glib2-dev on the target. Thanks Steve-o.